# Is it possible to save in app call in Recents log without using callkit?

Tags: swift, xcode, voip, callkit

I am developing a voice app with a custom call ui.
I wanted to show the custom ui when the app is in the foreground that's why I'm not calling `reportNewIncomingCall` or `reportOutgoingCall` when the app is in the foreground. This works perfectly but the call is not being saved in `Recents` logs of the phone.

I wanted to save the call in `Recents`, should I combine callkit and custom ui? Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: no i don't think it is possible. CallKit has access to alot more than you do yourself.

Comment: How can I prevent incoming call ui from callkit to show when my app is in the foreground? Because I want to show my custom ui if my app is in the foreground.